# javascript only-click image to open link

Tags: javascript, templates, addeventlistener, window.open

I'm going off a [template](https://codingartistweb.com/2021/11/product-filter-and-search-using-javascript/) that searches the page and displays various containers. Most of the work is in the script.js file. What I want to do I click on each image in the various containers and each one will go to a different local html page. I have seen examples where you can click on an image but they seem to refer to the html page  and I want this to be on the javascript part only (if possible), because I have nothing in my html to work with.

My html page is very simple. Here is the body:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div id="search-container">
            <input
              type="search"
              id="search-input"
              placeholder="Search plug-in name here.."
            />
            <button id="search">Search</button>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('all')">All</button>
            ......
        </div>
        <div id="products"></div>
</div>
```

As for the javascript part, that is the bulk of what happens. I mainly know html and css, so I don't understand everything in this part.

```
    let products = {
      data: [
        {
          productName: "ADSR Sample Manager",
          category: "Software",
          image: "sm_img/ADSR_Sample_Manager-260x390-01.jpg",
          link: "plug-ins/adsr-sample-manager.html",
        },
        {
          productName: "Beige Short Skirt",
          category: "Bottomwear",
          image: "short-skirt.jpg",
        },
        ......
      ],
    };

    for (let i of products.data) {
      //Create Card
      let card = document.createElement("div");
      //Card should have category and should stay hidden initially
      card.classList.add("card", i.category, "hide");
      //image div
      let imgContainer = document.createElement("div");
      imgContainer.classList.add("image-container");
      //img tag
      let image = document.createElement("img");
      image.setAttribute("src", i.image);
      
      // THIS FUNCTION opens _blank.
      image.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log("clicked");
        window.open(products.data.link, '_blank');
      });

      imgContainer.appendChild(image);
      card.appendChild(imgContainer);
      //container
      let container = document.createElement("div");
      container.classList.add("container");
      //product name
      let name = document.createElement("h5");
      name.classList.add("product-name");
      name.innerText = i.productName.toUpperCase();
      container.appendChild(name);

      //link IS THIS CORRECT?
      let link = document.createElement("div");
      container.appendChild(link);

      card.appendChild(container);
      document.getElementById("products").appendChild(card);
    }

    //Initially display all products
    window.onload = () => {
      filterProduct("all");
    };
```

Is the link part setup correctly? and the function() doesn't work, it opens _blank, not "plug-ins/adsr-sample-manager.html"

Since I don't know javascript very well, I'm sorry if my terms are all mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add a click event to each product image, you'd need to do the following:

```
image.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("clicked");
  window.open(i.link, "_blank");
})
```

`i.link` would be the specific link for the current `product.data` item and `_blank` simply tells the browser to open the link in a new page so it can be removed if that is not what you want.

Overall, going with this approach where the navigation happens with `window.open` means that you can't use features like middle click to open in a new tab.

a better approach would be to wrap the image in an anchor tag (link) and set the link on that:

```
//image link
let imageLink = document.createElement("a");
imageLink.setAttribute("href", i.link);
imgContainer.appendChild(imageLink);

//img tag
let image = document.createElement("img");
image.setAttribute("src", i.image);
imageLink.appendChild(image);
card.appendChild(imgContainer);
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<div class="image-container">
  <a href="/my-link-1"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked great by just adding 
`window.open(i.link, "_blank");`

Using the alternative one didn't work because if I add anything to the html page, the search javascript doesn't work.